# Algorithm ABBA(SRM 663, DIV 2, 500)

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

I am doing a problem from [*this blog*](http://oncecoder.blogspot.com.au/2015/08/abba-srm-663-div-2-500.html)

> One day, Jamie noticed that many English words only use the letters A and B. Examples of such words include "AB" (short for abdominal), "BAA" (the noise a sheep makes), "AA" (a type of lava), and "ABBA" (a Swedish pop sensation).
>
> Inspired by this observation, Jamie created a simple game. You are given two Strings: initial and target. The goal of the game is to find a sequence of valid moves that will change initial into target. There are two types of valid moves:
>
> Add the letter A to the end of the string.
> Reverse the string and then add the letter B to the end of the string.
> Return "Possible" (quotes for clarity) if there is a sequence of valid moves that will change initial into target. Otherwise, return "Impossible".

My Questions:

1. My solution follows example steps: Firstly, reverse and append 'B', then append 'A'. I have no idea whether I need to use another order of the step(firstly, append 'A', then reverse and append 'B') at same time.
2. I got "ABBA" which should return "Possible", but "Impossible" was returned.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(canContain("B","ABBA"));
}

public static String canContain(String Initial, String Target){ 
    
    char[] target = new char[1000];
    char[] initial1 = new char[1000];
    int flag = 0;
    boolean possible = false;
    int InitialLength = Initial.length();
    int TargetLength = Target.length();
    
    System.out.println("Initial:");
    int countInitial = -1;
    for(char x : Initial.toCharArray()){
        countInitial++;
        if(x=='A')initial1[countInitial]='A';
        if(x=='B')initial1[countInitial]='B';
        System.out.print(x+"->"+initial1[countInitial]+" ");
    }
    
    
    int countTarget = -1;
    System.out.println("\nTarget:");
    for(char y : Target.toCharArray()){
        countTarget++;
        if(y=='A')target[countTarget]='A';
        if(y=='B')target[countTarget]='B';
        System.out.print(y+"->"+target[countTarget]+" ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    
    
    
    //Check Initial char[]
    System.out.print("---------------");
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(int t1 = 0; t1 <= countInitial; t1++){
        System.out.print(initial1[t1]+"-");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(int t3 = 0; t3 <= countTarget; t3++){
        System.out.print(target[t3]+"-");
    }
    
    while(countInitial != countTarget){
        if(flag == 0 && Initial != Target){
            System.out.println("\n_______A_______");
            countInitial++;
            System.out.println("countInitial = "+countInitial);
            initial1[countInitial] = 'A';
            System.out.println(initial1[countInitial]);
            for(int t1 = 0; t1 <= countInitial; t1++){
                System.out.print(initial1[t1]+"-");
            }
            flag = 1;
        }else if(flag == 1 && Initial != Target){
            System.out.println("\n_______R_+_B_______");
            int ct = 0;
            char[] temp = new char[1000];
            for(int i = countInitial; i >= 0; i--){
                System.out.println("countInitial = "+countInitial);
                temp[ct] = initial1[i];
                System.out.println("ct = "+ct);
                ct++;
            }
            initial1 = temp;
            countInitial++;
            initial1[countInitial] = 'B';
            for(int t1 = 0; t1 < countInitial; t1++){
                System.out.print(initial1[t1]+"-");
            }
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    
    if(initial1.equals(target)){
        return "Possible";
    }else{
        return "Impossible";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: And what are the input constraints?

Comment: @Rishav String Initial and String Target cannot be null, and the length of Initial is less than the length of Target

Comment: No, the length of the initial and target strings are?

Comment: @Rishav  
- The length of initial will be between 1 and 999, inclusive. - The length of target will be between 2 and 1000, inclusive. - target will be longer than initial. - Each character in initial and each character in target will be either 'A' or 'B'.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that you apply rules in the particular order. However it is not forbidden to use the same rule multiple times in a row. So to get the target string from the initial you need to inspect all possible sequences of rule applications. This is known as combinatorial explosion.

Problems like this is usually easier to solve working backwards. If the target string is `xyzA` it may only be obtained by rule 1 from `xyz`. If the target string is `xyzB` it may only be obtained by rule 2 from `zyx`. So in pseudocode,

```
    while length(target) > length(initial)
        remove the last letter from target
        if removed letter is "B"
            reverse target
    if target == initial
        print "Possible"
    else
        print "Impossible"
```

Of course, reversal doesn't have to be explicit.

Comment: This method will not work because of the vast number of branches in the tree! To compute 2^999 possible strings is simply not feasible to compute. Dynamic programming has to be applied.

Comment: @Rishav Please reread the second paragraph. In pseudocode there is _no_ branching whatsoever.

Comment: @user58697 How do you know your condition can satisfy all of test cases? what if I apply rule 2 when target string is xyzA ? A test case is: "AB"->"ABB" Returns: "Impossible" The only strings of length 3 Jamie can create are "ABA" and "BAB". It shows there are 2 results, but your method seems like only gives 1 result.

Comment: @Rhodalala It seems that you miss the word "backwards". Do not apply the rule to the initial string. Undo an application from target instead. For example, "ABBA" can only be produced from "ABB", and "ABB" can only be produced from "BA", and "BA" only from "B". So if the initial is "ABB", "BA" or "B" the answer is "Possible".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which will run for a linear time O(n). The idea is that you start from the target string and try to revert the operations until you reach a string with the same length as the initial string. Then you compare these 2 strings. Here's the solution:

```
   private static final char A = 'A';
   private static final String POSSIBLE = "Possible";
   private static final String IMPOSSIBLE = "Impossible";

   public String canObtain(String initial, String target) {
      if (initial == null ||
            initial.trim().length() < 1 ||
            initial.trim().length() > 999) {
         return IMPOSSIBLE;
      }

      if (target == null ||
            target.trim().length() < 2 ||
            target.trim().length() > 1000) {
         return IMPOSSIBLE;
      }

      return isPossible(initial, target) ? POSSIBLE : IMPOSSIBLE;
   }

   private boolean isPossible(String initial, String target) {
      final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(target);
      while (initial.length() != sb.length()) {
         char targetLastChar = sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1);
         if (targetLastChar == A) {
            unApplyA(sb);
         } else {
            unApplyRevB(sb);
         }
      }

      return initial.equals(sb.toString());
   }

   private void unApplyA(StringBuilder sb) {
      sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
   }

   private void unApplyRevB(StringBuilder sb) {
      sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
      sb.reverse();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but this is a concise solution in Python that runs in linear time:

```
class ABBA:
    def canObtain(self, initial, target):
        if initial == target:
            return 'Possible'
        if len(initial) == len(target):
            return 'Impossible'
        if target[-1] == 'A':
            return self.canObtain(initial, target[:-1])
        if target[-1] == 'B':
            return self.canObtain(initial, target[:-1][::-1])
```